# How to guide a single Bessel-like field through a special single higher order mode fiber?

Tags: fiber-optics

As single mode fiber (SMF) guides fundamental mode/Gaussian mode. Is there any kind of special fiber that can guide a single higher order bessel like field to some propagation length without changing its shape? The Bessel-like field is shown below:

[image]

As conventional single mode fiber does not support this Bessel-like fields. So Is there any type of fiber available so that this bessel like beam can be guided to some distance or Is there any fiber which supports one single higher order mode through the fiber?